# Does .NET MVC work when System.Web.Mvc is loaded in the GAC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, assemblies, gac

**Is it allowed to put System.Web.Mvc in the GAC? Allowed as in: does it work?**

I have done this and all my projects have problems inheriting from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage...

**EDIT**
Hope this doesn't scare you:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE> "c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\vbc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\assembly\dl3\56b70440\003d6f34_8989c901\EntitySpaces.SqlServerCeProvider.DLL" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Abstractions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Abstractions.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\assembly\dl3\de7cc3b4\0097d136_8989c901\EntitySpaces.LoaderMT.DLL" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\assembly\dl3\2afa6c79\006aa035_8989c901\EntitySpaces.NpgsqlProvider.DLL" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\assembly\dl3\4a9a547a\006aa035_8989c901\EntitySpaces.OracleClientProvider.DLL" /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\assembly\dl3\ea5276d6\0051153a_699ec901\System.Web.Mvc.DLL" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\assembly\dl3\f8843c3a\0097d136_8989c901\EntitySpaces.Web.Design.DLL" /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\assembly\dl3\4137948d\003d6f34_8989c901\EntitySpaces.Npgsql2Provider.DLL" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\assembly\dl3\b72019d9\003d6f34_8989c901\EntitySpaces.MySqlClientProvider.DLL" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_global.asax.hiqvxvcm.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll" /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\assembly\dl3\ad4567e4\006aa035_8989c901\EntitySpaces.Loader.DLL" /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\assembly\dl3\b543038f\006aa035_8989c901\EntitySpaces.Core.DLL" /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\assembly\dl3\701637c6\003d6f34_8989c901\EntitySpaces.VistaDBProvider.DLL" /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_vpbbzwke.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\assembly\dl3\66dcb3ba\006aa035_8989c901\EntitySpaces.Web.DLL" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Routing\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Routing.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\EC\1.0.0.0__2fce90138e5217ab\EC.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\assembly\dl3\750052d7\716d39b6_bfd3c901\VandaagLijst.DLL" /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\assembly\dl3\d5308498\003d6f34_8989c901\EntitySpaces.MSAccessProvider.DLL" /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\assembly\dl3\5ad7a5b5\006aa035_8989c901\EntitySpaces.SqlClientProvider.DLL" /R:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\assembly\dl3\54566418\003d6f34_8989c901\EntitySpaces.Interfaces.DLL" /out:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.dll" /debug- /win32resource:"c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\p7uswgud.res" /define:_MYTYPE=\"Web\" /imports:Microsoft.VisualBasic,System,System.Collections,System.Collections.Specialized,System.Configuration,System.Text,System.Text.RegularExpressions,System.Web,System.Web.Caching,System.Web.SessionState,System.Web.Security,System.Web.Profile,System.Web.UI,System.Web.UI.WebControls,System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts,System.Web.UI.HtmlControls,System.Web.Mvc,System.Web.Mvc.Ajax,System.Web.Mvc.Html,System.Web.Routing,System.Linq,System.Collections.Generic,EC /warnaserror- /optionInfer+  "c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.0.vb" "c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.1.vb" "c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.2.vb" "c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.3.vb"
```

Microsoft (R) Visual Basic Compiler version 9.0.30729.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Bugging\VandaagLijst\VandaagLijst\Views\home\List.aspx(1) : error BC30456: 'Title' is not a member of 'ASP.views_home_list_aspx'.

```
        __ctrl.Title = ""
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

C:\Bugging\VandaagLijst\VandaagLijst\Views\home\List.aspx(1) : error BC30456: 'InitializeCulture' is not a member of 'ASP.views_home_list_aspx'.

```
        Me.InitializeCulture
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

C:\Bugging\VandaagLijst\VandaagLijst\Views\home\List.aspx(1) : error BC30456: 'MasterPageFile' is not a member of 'ASP.views_home_list_aspx'.

```
        __ctrl.MasterPageFile = "~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

C:\Bugging\VandaagLijst\VandaagLijst\Views\home\List.aspx(7) : error BC30456: 'AddContentTemplate' is not a member of 'ASP.views_home_list_aspx'.

```
        Me.AddContentTemplate("TitleContent", New System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder(AddressOf Me.__BuildControlContent1))
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

C:\Bugging\VandaagLijst\VandaagLijst\Views\home\List.aspx(11) : error BC30456: 'AddContentTemplate' is not a member of 'ASP.views_home_list_aspx'.

```
        Me.AddContentTemplate("MainContent", New System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder(AddressOf Me.__BuildControlContent2))
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

C:\Bugging\VandaagLijst\VandaagLijst\Views\home\List.aspx(13) : error BC30451: Name 'Model' is not declared.

```
       For Each item In Model
                        ~~~~~
```

c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.2.vb(42) : error BC30198: ')' expected.

```
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(of IEnumerable(of Models.TestClass)
                                                                       ~
```

c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.2.vb(43) : error BC30154: Class 'views_home_list_aspx' must implement 'ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean' for interface 'System.Web.IHttpHandler'. Implementing property must have matching 'ReadOnly' or 'WriteOnly' specifiers.

```
    Implements System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState, System.Web.IHttpHandler
                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.2.vb(43) : error BC30149: Class 'views_home_list_aspx' must implement 'Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext)' for interface 'System.Web.IHttpHandler'.

```
    Implements System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState, System.Web.IHttpHandler
                                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.2.vb(55) : error BC30311: Value of type 'ASP.views_home_list_aspx' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage'.

```
        CType(Me,Global.System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage).AppRelativeVirtualPath = "~/Views/home/List.aspx"
              ~~
```

c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.2.vb(57) : error BC30456: 'ReadStringResource' is not a member of 'ASP.views_home_list_aspx'.

```
            Global.ASP.views_home_list_aspx.__stringResource = Me.ReadStringResource
                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.2.vb(61) : error BC30456: 'GetWrappedFileDependencies' is not a member of 'ASP.views_home_list_aspx'.

```
            Global.ASP.views_home_list_aspx.__fileDependencies = Me.GetWrappedFileDependencies(dependencies)
                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.2.vb(68) : error BC30456: 'Context' is not a member of 'ASP.views_home_list_aspx'.

```
            Return CType(Me.Context.Profile,System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile)
                         ~~~~~~~~~~
```

c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.2.vb(74) : error BC30456: 'Context' is not a member of 'ASP.views_home_list_aspx'.

```
            Return CType(Me.Context.ApplicationInstance,ASP.global_asax)
                         ~~~~~~~~~~
```

c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.2.vb(193) : error BC30284: sub 'FrameworkInitialize' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a sub in a base class.

```
    Protected Overrides Sub FrameworkInitialize()
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.2.vb(195) : error BC30456: 'SetStringResourcePointer' is not a member of 'ASP.views_home_list_aspx'.

```
        Me.SetStringResourcePointer(Global.ASP.views_home_list_aspx.__stringResource, 0)
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.2.vb(197) : error BC30456: 'AddWrappedFileDependencies' is not a member of 'ASP.views_home_list_aspx'.

```
        Me.AddWrappedFileDependencies(Global.ASP.views_home_list_aspx.__fileDependencies)
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.2.vb(201) : error BC30284: function 'GetTypeHashCode' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a function in a base class.

```
    Public Overrides Function GetTypeHashCode() As Integer
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\24f69041\8efa8a35\App_Web_p7uswgud.2.vb(206) : error BC30284: sub 'ProcessRequest' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a sub in a base class.

```
    Public Overrides Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpContext)
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: perhaps some more context around the problem you're having would help. Can you not find ViewPage? Does it compile? Does it fail at runtime?

Comment: I can compile. At runtime it says: Title is not a member of ASP.views_index_aspx. I can however not find the class views_index_aspx. I have reason to believe that this is generated in the background. However in the wrong namespace i guess (ASP), which should be (MyProject) right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works at runtime. You still need to have a referenced assembly. How are you referencing the assemblies for your build/VS.NET environment?

As you can see from here...

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx

... the default is to install these assemblies into the GAC and you have to explicity work around this if you want to bin-deploy your MVC assemblies (for example, in a shared hosting situation).

Comment: I have referenced the assembly in VS, set the copy-local to false. In my WebSetup deployment project I have set the assembly to Exclude (assembly is in GAC also on production server => which is the same pc :P).

Comment: It looks (though it's not clear) from your edits above that you have at least one syntax error in there (a missing closing bracket). However, what would also be useful would be to see the first few lines of the .aspx file - the Page declaration in particular.

Are you using the RTM build of ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: The declaration doesn't look wrong:
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(of IEnumerable(of VandaagLijst.Models.Workorder))" %> ... However I somehow managed to get it working by removing/re-referencing System.Web.Mvc, and by re-creating the View from the Controller action (right-click: create view...)

Comment: Oh by the way, I'm NOT referencing the assembly from the GAC anymore. I gave up :-)